# Online/Offline Image Management Strategy

Tags: android, image, web-services, sqlite, drawable

I am working on an app that will *get data and images from the `webservice` and store it in device for offline usage*. At the same time the application will have some data stored in `sqlite db` and some images as the default data.

**Here is the flow of app:**

- When the application opens it will grab the data from `Sqlite Db` and
  image paths of images stored in device and display them.
- Beside that if there is internet connection, data and images from
  `webservice` will be consumed and copied to the **`Sqlite DB(data)`**
  and to the **`device(images)`** to be later accessed offline

**Here is the question:**

> What is the best strategy to do that (note that i want also to prevent
>   images shown in gallery of the device. They will be able to be accesed
>   only from the app)?

- Should i store default images firstly in `Assets Folder` and copy
  them to the *external directory* on the first oppening. And for *offline
  usage of the images from the webservice*, download and save them to the
  same directory?
- Should i store local images in drawables and downloaded images in
  external directory of the device?
- Should i store all images in SqliteDb as binary data (which i dont
  prefer because of performance)

Also take in consideration that i want to store multiple images for different device sizes. So on the first opening i check the device from which `drawable folder (xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi)` it takes the images like so:

```
 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
switch(metrics.densityDpi){
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
                    break;
            }
```

store to what folder it goes on `SharedPreferences`so when i download images from the service, it will go *to the specific folder with specfic image sizes* of `webservice` and grap them

> What is the best and easy strategy to manage images in this case?

[note: I dont want to use `google extension files` as the data and images can be udated frequently]

Answer (score 2):

> Should i store default images firstly in Assets Folder and copy them to the external directory on the first oppening. And for offline usage of the images from the webservice, download and save them to the same directory?

No. Get them from server when you start application and use caching mechanism so when internet is not available then it will fetch from cache folder. For these you can use picasso library that do this stuff very nicely.

> Should i store all images in SqliteDb as binary data (which i dont prefer because of performance)

No, you should not store images in sqlite db because this can make your app database size huge. Generally if we want to do these types of stuff then we only store image path not binary file.

> What is the best and easy strategy to manage images in this case?

When you call a service to get a bitmap, there check device density then send height and width to server then expect from it to return in that size like fetchImage?image_width=xxx&image_height=yyy

Comment: The thing is that at the same time i will get other data as `json` where the name of the images will be there too, `insert` them in `SqliteDB` of the device and then download images also and store them in the device.
For the app to not be empty of the data. Firstly the DB will be copied to the device from assets folder and some images have to be there also. 
From your explanation i understand that for offline usage i have to use `chaching mechanism` but would be problem if i have a lot of images?

Comment: @hrskrs No, it should not create any problem. Afaik how this others app do this thing

Comment: with `picasso` if i am not wrong you can download an image at a time. It doesnt support multiple images. Or maybe with looping this can be solved. There is [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) out there which from my research it looks best for my case. And i am afraid that if user cleans cache. The data will be left on SqliteDB but images wont be available, i read that images should be stored in external directory when downloaded

Comment: Hmm I see. If user clear cache then images will start download again. if you save in external directory then you need to create directory and create .nomedia file in it otherwise these saved files will be seen in gallery app

Comment: Yeah thats what i am planning. Do you know any good library or example that does that job?

Comment: For downloading multiple images at once and store them in external storage with .nomedia

Comment: @hrskrs No sorry I don't have any idea of that